# How to fix WordPress HTTPS issues when behind an Amazon Load Balancer?

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, https, amazon-elb

I've had this issue before.  When running WordPress (or other PHP scripts) behind Amazon's EC2 Load Balancer, the scripts do not realize they are being ran on the https:// protocol and results in issues such as endless redirect loops, and HTTPS warnings ("Some content on this page is being requested in a non-secure way...").

I found a solution here, but requires modifying WordPress core, which is no good for updatability:
https://wordpress.org/support/topic/when-behind-amazon-web-services-elastic-load-balancer-causes-endless-redirect

Is there a way to fix this without modifying WordPress core?  I am using Apache 2.2.

Answer (score 89, accepted):

Like the link, you gave suggested, for WordPress the issue lies in the `is_ssl()` function, which like most PHP software explicitly checks the `$_SERVER['HTTPS']` and `$_SERVER['SERVER_PORT']` to check if the current page is being accessed in the https:// context.

When your page is accessed over HTTPS, but the Amazon Load Balancer is performing SSL offloading and actually requesting your content on the non-SSL port 80, the webserver, PHP, or anything else for that matter, does not understand or see that it's being accessed over https://.

The fix for this is that Amazon's ELB sends the de-facto standard `X-Forwarded-Proto` HTTP header, which we can use to figure out which protocol the client is *actually* using on the other side of the Load Balancer.

With Apache 2.2, you could use something along the lines of:

```
<IfModule mod_setenvif.c>
  SetEnvIf X-Forwarded-Proto "^https$" HTTPS
</IfModule>
```

This simply reads the `X-Forwarded-Proto` header. If this value equals `https` then the `HTTPS` environment variable is set to `1`.  PHP will see this environment variable, and eventually, it will become `$_SERVER['HTTPS']` that equals `1` -- just like it would be for a "real" native SSL request.

Comment: Works fine, you need to make sure you've enabled the apache2 module setenvif.

Comment: simply added to the apache configuration (image from bitnami) and it works.

Comment: Note that many proxy situations use X-Forwarded-Scheme in a synonmous fashion.  Generally safe to set both.

Comment: Works on Apache2.4 as well

Comment: This answer works best for me because it doesn't only just work on Wordpress, it works on Laravel as well.

Answer (score 43):

Another option from the [WordPress documentation](https://wordpress.org/support/article/administration-over-ssl/#using-a-reverse-proxy) is to add this to your wp-config.php:

```
if (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'], 'https') !== false)
       $_SERVER['HTTPS']='on';
```

Comment: This is the method I used.  Any idea how to force people to HTTPS if they access the page via HTTP?

Comment: You could try adding `force_ssl_content(true);` to the wp-config.php as well. Normally I would do that via an Apache rewrite rule or in the load balancer config though.

Comment: @MattWiner if you're using AWS ELB, you need to configure a separate listener on port 80, route that through to your EC2 server on another port (81 for example) and there do a url rewrite to redirect any requests to the HTTPS version of the original URL. Then the web browser will request the HTTPS url instead.

Comment: Simple and clean solution +1. Worked for my WordPress site serving on HTTP behind AWS load balancer, which has SSL enabled.

Comment: you can now configure redirects from http to https on the application load balancer directly

Answer (score 15):

In case anyone else was looking for the Nginx equivalent to this, here's what you need to do:

To ensure browsers use https, you can add the following under the `server` block:

```
if ($http_x_forwarded_proto != 'https') {
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
```

And for setting the HTTPS param you should add the following under the `location ~ \.php$` block:

```
if ($http_x_forwarded_proto = 'https') {
    set $fe_https 'on';
}
fastcgi_param HTTPS $fe_https;
```

Remember to remove any other `fastcgi_param HTTPS` command if you have any (I had it in my `fastcgi_params` file).

Comment: You saved my butt in production! Cheers!

Comment: Glad to help. Cheers  :)

Answer (score 14):

Use this 4 step method to remove the redirect loop and mixed content problems when using ssl in WordPress.

1) Replace 'http://' with '//' in database - This create all the relative url's for images and other assets

2) in wp-config, define generic wp_home and wp_siteurl variables.

```
define('WP_HOME','//'. $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']);
define('WP_SITEURL','//'. $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']);
```

3) If you are using load balancer, use 'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO' server variable to figure out protocol used. To do this, add this line in wp-config

```
if (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'], 'https') !== false)
$_SERVER['HTTPS']='on';
```

4) Finally in .htaccess, use this line if you are behind loadbalancer to redirect all traffic to https.

```
 # http to https
 RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} =http
 RewriteRule . https://%{HTTP:Host}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=permanent]
```

Comment: On your step 1, where in the database?

Comment: This solution could be pointed out the ELB from port 443 to 80

Answer (score 5):

Neither of the above solved the Mixed Content errors for me unfortunately. However what did work was adding the protocol to the WP_HOME && WP_SITEURL variables in wp-config.php e.g.

`define( 'WP_HOME', 'https://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
 define( 'WP_SITEURL', WP_HOME );`

After that all URLs in the source began with https and all the Mixed Content errors disappeared.

Answer (score 2):

My Server Environment is:
`Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS, PHP 8.0.11, nginx/1.18.0`

The following settings in `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default` worked for me:

```
server {

    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    root /var/www/html;
    index  index.php index.html index.htm;
    server_name ChangeDomainName.com www.ChangeDomainName.com;

    if ($http_x_forwarded_proto != 'https') {
        rewrite ^ https://$host$request_uri? permanent;
    }

    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }
    location ~ \.php$ {
            include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php8.0-fpm.sock;
            if ($http_x_forwarded_proto = 'https') {
                set $fe_https 'on';
            }
            fastcgi_param HTTPS $fe_https;
            fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Regarding almost perfect @A.B. Carroll answer, I would suggest to set this enviroment variable to "on":

```
<IfModule mod_setenvif.c>
  SetEnvIf X-Forwarded-Proto "^https$" HTTPS=on
</IfModule>
```

In my Dockerfile I am including this line to solve Apache issues with working behind reverse proxy (ie Traeffik):

```
RUN echo "<IfModule mod_setenvif.c>\nSetEnvIf X-Forwarded-Proto \"^https$\" HTTPS=on\n</IfModule>" > /etc/apache2/conf-enabled/ssl_offload.conf
```