# Wordpress get_template_directory_uri() returns http instead of https

Tags: wordpress, ssl, https

We have recently applied SSL certificate on our website and we want all our url to have https:// protocol.

Once we moved our website to https://, our website broke down as there were few resource which were still pointing to http://. After researching for a while, I saw that get_template_directory_uri() is always returning http:// even through our wp_home, wp_site_url is set with https://

Is there any other place where we have to change the URL, as we are using child theme and this function get the parent theme directory.

Thanks,
Raju Vishwas

Comment: What have you set "WP_CONTENT_URL" as ? I tend to set things in wp-config.php for https - I can give you my full set up if that might help

Comment: Sure, let me check about that.

Comment: Were you able to solve this?

Comment: @Simon Pollard I know this was a long time ago,but I'm now facing the same problem, so can you give me a clue how to update my wp-config.php file to solve the case? Thank!!!!

Comment: Check if the server is returning HTTPS, in my case we were using Load Balancer server and the SSL certificate was install on load balancer, so my apache was always returning http instead of https, I had to hard code to return https

Comment: @RajuVishwas I'm facing the same issue (using Load Balancer)...could you please told me how exactly did you "hard code" it to return https? Thank you!

Answer (score 13):

Check the `$_SERVER['HTTPS']` value. This should be set to `on` or `1`. If it has any other value while being set, this function will output http rather than https.

See: https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.5.3/src/wp-includes/functions.php#L4025

Comment: it's $_SERVER['HTTPS']

Comment: @Juergen thanks, I capitalized it in the answer now too.

Answer (score 7):

Going by this comment the initiator added:

> in my case we were using Load Balancer server and the SSL certificate
>   was install on load balancer

The answer from @pbond scratches the surface to the root cause of the issue. 
The WordPress `is_ssl()` function checks the $_SERVER['HTTPS'] and $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] to check if the current page is being accessed via https but the load balancer is most likely requesting your content on the non-SSL port 80.

One good fix for this is to use the `X-Forwareded-Proto` HTTP header to figure out which protocol the client is actually using on the other side of the Load Balancer.

With Apache 2.2, you could add this to your configuration:

```
<IfModule mod_setenvif.c>
  SetEnvIf X-Forwarded-Proto "^https$" HTTPS
</IfModule>
```

Another possible fix (alluded to by @Roberto Poblete but not explained) is to add this to `wp-config.php`

```
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO']) && $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'] == 'https')
$_SERVER['HTTPS'] = 'on';
```

I have [this to thank](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30702491/1131990) for sending me in the right direct

Answer (score 5):

This worked for me like a charm, added to *wp-config* at the end:

```
define('FORCE_SSL_ADMIN', true);
define('WP_HOME', 'https://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
define('WP_SITEURL', WP_HOME);
```

Comment: Thx, this was enough to fix it.

Answer (score 4):

view notes of link 
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_ssl

```
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO']) && $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'] == 'https')
$_SERVER['HTTPS'] = 'on';
```

Comment: Add some explanation with answer for how this answer help OP in fixing current issue

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to force content delivery through https with a modified .htaccess file?

below the snippet I'm using:

```
#Force HTTPS
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the list of plugins installed. Any plugin involving caching, CDNs etc may interfere with get_template_directory_uri. In our case the customer had installed a ton of plugins to supposedly speed up his site.

With no plugins enabled https loaded fine. So it was just a case of figuring out which one it was. And buried in the offending plugin's settings there was an http version of the site path.

Answer (score 0):

if(
isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO']) &&
$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO']="https"
)
$_SERVER['HTTPS']="on";

helps in my case
in wp-config.php

My server not returns this server header in https:// urls!

Answer (score -2):

Please use the following:

```
get_stylesheet_directory_uri();
```

it will be a web-address (starting with http:// or https:// for SSL). As such, it is most appropriately used for links, referencing additional stylesheets, or probably most commonly, images.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_stylesheet_directory_uri

Comment: `get_template_directory_uri()` also returns a URI...and checks for SSL. They're both useful, but switching to `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()` *does* make more sense in this instance, because the OP is using a child theme.

Comment: The problem is, our theme is using get_template_directory_uri() and get_stylesheet_directory_uri() but it still returning http://

Comment: Do you SSL installed for your domain?

Comment: Yes, we have SSL installed but currently you can access website from http:// as well as https://

Comment: Did you change both URL from http: to https: at  www.yourdomain.com/wp-admin/options-general.php?

Comment: Hi @AtifTariq, yes I have changed the setting from database too, but it will still not return https://

Comment: Hi Raju, please try these plugins:    https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-force-ssl/                       https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-https/